# How to set a permission after creating a directory using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code. In my code there is a part that can generate a directory in the server and when I checked the directory in the FTP the initial folder is generated but the subfolders are not and when I try to open the main folder there is a log that says:

```
Response:   550 /httpdocs/ecommerce/image/catalog/sellers/826: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

When I checked the newly created main folder it contains this permission:

```
e(01411)
```

In my code I have this:

```
public function addUser($data) {

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "user` SET username = '" . $this->db->escape($data['username']) . "', shop_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shop_name']) . "', user_group_id = '" . (int)$data['user_group_id'] . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', image = '" . $this->db->escape($data['image']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
    $get_customer_id = $this->db->getLastId();

    $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/sellers/' . $get_customer_id;

    if(!file_exists($directory)) {

        mkdir($directory, 777);

        mkdir($directory . '/profile', 777);
        mkdir($directory . '/banner', 777);
        mkdir($directory . '/products', 777);

    }

}
```

In my localhost it is working properly but when I upload it has an error.
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your permissions settings are missing a leading (octal) zero.

From the manual on chmod:

```
<?php
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 755);   // decimal; probably incorrect
chmod("/somedir/somefile", "u+rwx,go+rx"); // string; incorrect
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // octal; correct value of mode
?>
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Sidenote:

Personally, I think the folks at PHP.net should update their page regarding *"probably incorrect"* adding some clarification.

Comment: Sidenote: I didn't see the other answer, as it took me that much more time to get the information from the PHP.net's website and typing it up.

Comment: Ok thanks but what do you mean by `probably incorrect` ?

Comment: @Jerielle You're welcome. I didn't write that,  I pulled it from an example on PHP.net have a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php Personally, I think they should update their page.

Comment: Probably incorrect probably means "your mileage may vary", because that is how it is expected to be, but some platforms may be forgiving any allow it in any case.

Comment: @crafter that makes sense, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying the permissions using an octal number with leading zero?
[The PHP manual for `mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) says...

> Note that you probably want to specify the mode as an octal number, which means it should have a leading zero.

Try...

```
mkdir($directory, 0777);
```